# Poker split / side pots

Tags: algorithms

I am writing a poker application and trying to figure out how to deal with split pots and side pots

There are four rounds of betting and each round of betting can have multiple orbits

Can only bet the chips in front of you
So if a player is all in a side pot is created

Hands can tie - in which case the pot is split
If it does not spit evenly the 'last aggressor (raise)' gets the odd chip(s)

If you are raised you must call or fold
If you fold you lose your bets even if the hand wins
You cannot just cap you betting and create a side pot
You only create a side pot if you are all in

PlayerA all in 40 Win
PlayerB 80 second
PlayerC 80 last

Player A would take 120 (win 80 as 40 was his money in)
Player B would take  80

But you don't know the win order until the end
And when PlayerA went in you don't know how many people are going to call

What could be good algorithm for this?

This code is C# but really just looking for an approach.

My initial thought is to just record all the betting for each player
street, orbit, bet

Where that gets messy is that in a single orbit you could have multiple players all in for different amounts (bet)

And a different amount is not just all in
Player could be raised and then fold
In that case you know they lose but you still don't know who they lose to

There are rarely more than 3 orbits in a round
You could assume there would never be more than 10 as with min raise players would run out of chip

Comment: You can store the bets, who made them, and whether they went all in when the players make the bets.  Preserve this data until the game is decided.  And then distribute the pot according to the rules.  So not having the information until the game is decided does not have to be a problem.

Comment: To add to @KaspervandenBerg's comment, in business applications, one approach to persistence is called Event Sourcing.  The idea  is that instead of trying to maintain the current state from change requests, which are discarded after applied, instead the change requests are directly persisted in an events stream such as an append-only log.  There are some practical advantages of this (especially when it comes to restarting a failed process), and it looks a bit like what you might need.

Comment: @KaspervandenBerg Yes that was my thought.  Looking for more detail and a chance someone had actually done this.

Comment: The more I think about it I only need to know their total bet.  If they are not folded then they are all in.   First settle up that amount.  The caveat there is that I am not sure from the rules of poker if an all in has a claim to folded money.

Comment: Looked it up an yes and an all in has claim to folded money only up to the amount they are all in.

Comment: @KaspervandenBerg Whether they are all-in isn't relevant - the key thing is the committed chips for each player.

Comment: @ErikEidt This sort of thing is useful for hand histories but again, not relevant for this calculation.

Comment: I don't get the close based on debugging or writing existing code.  There is no existing code for split pots.  If I posted on SO it would get closed for not code.

Comment: @Paparazzi N.B. there are four rounds in hold 'em - pre-flop, post-flop, turn (4th street) and river (5th street).

Comment: @Paparazzi, did this ever get solved? I'm running into the same problem with a project of mine.

Comment: @EdwardRusu Yes and no.  Pretty sure the drive is good but the hard drive is dead.   And it is Win 10 app that I don't have another Win 10 to run it on.

Comment: Currently the universal rule in casinos is to award any odd chip to the eldest hand (first to act).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code to create and distribute winnings from side-pots.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, l, i, hs):
        self.live = l #False
        self.invested = i #0
        self.hand_strength = hs #100
        self.result = 0

def distribute(pot, players):
    for p in players:
        p.result= -p.invested # invested money is lost originally

    # while there are still players with money
    # we build a side-pot matching the lowest stack and distribute money to winners
    while len(players)>1 :
        min_stack = min([p.invested for p in players])
        pot += min_stack * len(players)
        for p in players:
            p.invested -= min_stack
        max_hand = max([p.hand_strength for p in players if p.live])
        winners = [p for p in players if p.hand_strength == max_hand if p.live]
        for p in winners:
            p.result += pot / len(winners)
        players = [p for p in players if p.invested > 0]
        pot = 0
    if len(players) == 1:
        p = players[0]
        # return uncalled bet
        p.result += p.invested
```

This example shows a case where there are 5 players and the starting pot is 100.
The main pot is split between player who are allin for 20 and 80. One player has folded after investing 50 and his best hand is wasted. One player has overbet all others and his bet is returned to him while he loses only the amount matched by the other players (80)

```
players = [Player(True, 20, 100),  Player(False, 50, 200),  Player(True, 80, 90),  Player(True, 80, 100), Player(True, 1000, 0)]
distribute(100, players)
for p in players:
    print(p.result)
#80.0
#-50
#-80
#230.0
#-80
```

Answer (score 3):

In my code, after every player has spoken, for every stake in the **set** of stakes of the players who are still in play, i create a pot. Then i order the pots from the smallest (that will be the main pot) to the highest (side pots).
The side pots are represented as a list, in this format:
[ needed stake, pot amount].

For the main pot, the "pot amount" will be equal to:
"needed stake" * number of players (including the ones who folded) whit a stake equal or higher than "needed stake".

For the remaining pots, the "pot amount" will be equal to: 
("needed stake" - needed stake of the pot preceding this one in the list) * number of players whit a stake equal or higher than "needed stake"

Answer (score 1):

**The basic algorithm is the dead chips (folds) + the minimum committed chips are distributed among the winners of the hand (main pot). If after this, there are still chips left in the pot, the process is repeated (for every side pot).**

So let's say at the end of a hand there were three players all-in and $300 in dead chips:

P1 shoved $50, P2 shoved $100 and P3 shoved $150.

**Scenario 1**

If the hands were equal (3 way pot), everyone would get $150 in the first iteration.

In the next, P2 & P3 would collect an additional $50. In the final iteration, P3 would collect an additional $50.

So the winnings would be:

P1 $150

P2 $200

P3 $250

**Scenario 2**

Let us assume here that P1 wins.

P1 collects $450 (his $50 and $50 each from P2 & P3 + $300 dead chips).

In the next iteration, let's say neither hand wins outright (board flush). P2 would collect side pot 1 ($50) and P3 would collect side pot 2 ($100).

Comment: I am aware of the rules of poker and I don't have ante in my game.  The question is how to create an algorithm.

Comment: See paragraph in bold - I've taken out the ante bit. Are you coding a particular poker variant (e.g. seven card stud, Omaha or hold 'em etc) or are you writing your own?

Comment: Texas Holdem and yes I am writing a program.  If that an algorithm then I don't follow.   It is not possible to have no winners.  Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Sorry, I meant winner in that particular iteration. I've added another scenario to clarify.

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help but again I am not asking about the rules of poker.  If that bold paragraph defines an algorithm then it is lost on me.

Comment: I'll try to find my code (also C# strangely enough) and see if I can knock up some pseudo code. You basically need three bits of info: 1) Who has won 2) The dead chip count 3) The committed chips for each player.

Comment: I've added some bits to clarify where the side and main pots come in. Also see [here](http://poker.stackexchange.com/a/464/683) for a decent description.

Comment: Yep, just pulled my code and it is exactly as I've described but from your answer, it seems like you've got it anyway.

Comment: I think the description here is not quite correct -- folded players may have chips in multiple pots as well, so you can't just place all of their bet into the main pot, you instead place up to the minimum all-in bet into that pool, just as with the live players. There is no difference between live vs. folded players with respect to which pots their money goes in, the only difference is that folded players cannot win and do not cause additional pots to be created for amounts above the amount they bet.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock For sure - there can be dead chips at any of the 4 betting levels. The scenarios are hugely simplified for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

Only track total bet by player and if they are folded or not

1)  determine minimum bet from all player in the pot
    and player not folded

2)  remove that amount from the every player (including folded) bet
    and sum it into a side-pot

3)  based on hand strength divvy up that side pot to player stacks
    if a split (tie) and there are odd chips then assign my hand position at the table

4)  reset side-pot to zero (plus left over)

5)  go to 1) if any player any player has any bet left
    (a hand cannot end with every hand folded)

Comment: Looks like I don't need to track last aggressor.  Just split any left over by the order in the hand.   That is how some of the existing commercial betting sites do it.

Comment: That is more or less it - step 1 is initially the main pot and includes dead chips (players who have folded). Odd chips typically go to the first winner to the dealer's left.

Comment: @RobbieDee This approach is not creating initial pots and side pots.  Split the main pot and side pots without defining an algorithm for creating the pots is not an algorithm.

Comment: I wouldn't get hung up on the terminology. If you find it easier to consider everything to be a side pot then fair enough.

Comment: @RobbieDee Yes you can look at it a lot of ways.  If you are going to look at side pots then the algorithm needs to define how side pot are created.  Your answer is split the side pots and yet fails to define the algorithm for side pots.

Comment: The principle is the same whether you do it on the fly to visually display the side pots or whether you do it at the end. I did mine at the end initially and was worried I'd calculated it wrong and did it on the fly too as a sense check - exactly the same algorithm.

Comment: This is basically what ended up with in my answer below but I think there are two things missing from this.  In step 1, it's not necessary to exclude folder players.  I've also added a step to handle the rare (but legal) case where all players fold after betting in a side pot.

Answer (score 0):

First determine if the round of betting has finished. i.e. all players have acted, AND EITHER all remaining players have met the price (the biggest bet) OR they have gone all-in.  Only if the round of betting has finished do you start adding chips to pots.

**Algorithm:**

Each player has a stack, and a hasBet amount, which is the amount of money they're betting before it gets added to a pot.

1. Take the lowest hasBet
2. For every player left in the hand, add that amount to the pot, and subtract it from the player's hasBet
3. Are there at least 2 players left with hasBet > 0?

YES: start a new pot, go to (1)

NO: go to (4)

4. Is this an all-in/cards-up situation? (i.e. all players are all-in, or all players are all in except one, so there are no more betting rounds).

YES: return any remaining hasBet chips to that player, deal all the remaining cards, and determine winners (multiple pots can mean multiple winners).

NO: deal the next card and move to the next round.

**Example (python)**

```
if all_in_situation:
    add_chips_to_pot()
    cards_up_scenario()  # no more betting, deal all remaining cards
elif all_players_have_acted and all_players_have_met_price_or_shoved:
    add_chips_to_pot()
    move_to_next_stage()   # stage being flop, turn, etc
else:
    increment_action()     # action moves on to the next player


def add_chips_to_pot(self):

    lowest_bet = work_out_lowest_bet() # omitted for brevity

    current_pot_index = len(self.pots) - 1   # i.e. if there are 2 pots, the one we want is at index 1
    
    for player in self.players:
        if player.has_bet == 0:
            continue
        self.pots[current_pot_index].amount = self.pots[current_pot_index].amount + lowest_bet
        self.pots[current_pot_index].players.append(player)
        player.has_bet = player.has_bet - lowest_bet

    players_with_hasbet_remaining = work_this_out() # omitted for brevity

    if players_with_hasbet_remaining > 1:
        self.pots.append(Pot())
        self.add_chips_to_pot()
    else:
        return
```

..where `self.pots` is a list of `Pot`s, and a `Pot` has 2 properties: the pot amount and a list of players that are in that Pot, which we need when determining the winner of each pot. You can have whatever data structures you like to achieve the same thing.

**Split pots**

You'll need a way of determining hand strength, which is beyond the scope of this question. To handle split pots we can say that each `Pot` has a list of winners.

```
def determine_winners(self):  

    for pot in self.pots:

        winners = []     # multiple winners if split pot  
        winning_score = 0
        for player in pot.players:
            if player.score == winning_score:
                winners.append(player)
            elif player.score > winning_score:
                winners = []
                winning_score = player.score
                winners.append(player)

        number_of_winners = len(pot.winners)
        for winner in pot.winners:
            winner.stack = winner.stack + (pot.amount / number_of_winners)  # division assumes ints, not decimals
            # return any spare chips from a split pot to the player in earliest position
            spare = pot.amount % number_of_winners
            self.players[0].stack = self.players[0].stack + spare
```

Note here that I'm returning spare chips left over from the split to the player in earliest position, which I believe is the common rule, but you can do whatever you want with them.